# Input the appropriate value (name) instead of (id) in phpmyadmin using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Can anyone tell me why my code input value (id) and not the (name) at the dropdown menus

[image]

1. This user interfaces

```
    <?php
    $sql_provinsi = mysqli_query(
        $con,
        "SELECT * FROM provinces ORDER BY name ASC"
    ); 
    ?>
    <select class="form-control" name="provinsi" id="provinsi" required>
        <option></option>
        <?php while (
        $rs_provinsi = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_provinsi)
    ) {
        echo '<option value="' .
            $rs_provinsi["id"] .
            '">' .
            $rs_provinsi["name"] .
            "</option>";
    } ?>
    </select>
```

2. This to post on phpmyadmin

```
if(isset($_POST['bsimpan']))
  {
    $simpan = mysqli_query($koneksi, 
                          "INSERT INTO custa (nama, wa, provinsi, kota, kecamatan, kelurahan, alamat, paket)
                           VALUES  ('$_POST[tnama]',
                                    '$_POST[twa]',
                                    '$_POST[provinsi]',
                                   )"
                           );
```

Comment: Please note: The database is MYSQL, not PHPMYADMIN. The latter is only a administration app for the database.

Comment: You really want to insert the name of the province into the dB so e.g. ' Sumatera' and not only an id and store those names  in an extra table connected via foreign key?

Comment: It does that because html selects post back the data in the "value" attribute of the selected option. But this is a **good** thing for your database, because then you get a unique ID which identifies the row, not a potentially changeable or ambiguous description. If you post back the name, your data will become denormalised. I suspect you need to study database design a bit more.

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks! You should use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of using completely unescaped user data directly in your queries like that. _Never ever ever never_ trust user input.

Comment: @ADyson but how to convert that value (id) to (name) ? because i need it on my mysql

Comment: No, you don't need it in your mysql. Read our comments again. Inserting the ID is the correct thing to do. That field in your custa table should be a foreign key back to the ID in the provinces table. Again, if you don't understand this, please study database design in more detail because it's a concept you would learn fairly early on in that topic.

Answer (score 2):

Because you put the id inside the value attribute. Try this.

```
echo '<option value="'.$rs_provinsi['name'].'">'.$rs_provinsi['name'].'</option>';
```

Comment: it works, but the rest of the dropdown not showing anymore